# xsd: multiple choice without repetition

Tags: xml, xsd, sequence, repeat

I need a XML like this:

```
<permission>
     <userType>Root</userType>
     <userType>Admin</userType>
 </permission>
```

and the values are from an enumeration like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="USERS"> 
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> 
        <xs:enumeration value="Root"/> 
        <xs:enumeration value="Admin"/> 
        <xs:enumeration value="User"/> 
        <xs:enumeration value="Guest"/> 
    </xs:restriction> 
</xs:simpleType>
```

the problem is that how I've it right now it accepts repeated values.

```
<xs:element name="permission">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="userType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="USERS"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

how can I do it, so that there's only 1 occurrence of each value available in the enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an uniqueness constraint for the contents of `userType`:

```
<xs:element name="permission">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="userType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="USERS"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniqueUserType">
        <xs:selector xpath="userType"/>
        <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

With this constraint, a duplicate name in `userType` will not validate:

```
<permission>
    <userType>Root</userType>
    <userType>Admin</userType>
    <userType>Admin</userType>
</permission>
```

*If your schema declares a target namespace*, you will need to declare a *prefix* for it so that it can be found by the XPath expression (which considers non-prefixed selectors as belonging to no-namespace), even if you have a default namespace declared. For example, you will need to have:

```
<xs:schema ... targetNamespace="my-namespace" xmlns:prefix="mynamespace"> ...
```

and use that prefix in your location paths:

```
<xs:selector xpath="prefix:userType"/>
```